# Meteor and ReactJS - Date retrieved from MongoDB to String?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, reactjs, meteor

I'm following Meteor tutorial with ReactJS variant and making some experiments in the meanwhile. I'm new to Meteor, React and Mongo. My background is PHP, SQL and JS.

Currently I have a collection(table) 'tasks' which stores documents(rows) containing a 'text' field of type string and a 'createdAt' field of type Date.

To allow the displaying of a 'task', the following code is used:

```
// Task component - represents a single todo item
export default class Task extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <li>
        <span className="text">{this.props.task.text}</span>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, I want to display the 'createdAt' property of the task. Knowing that it comes from a javascript Date type I try the following:

```
return (
    <li>
       <span className="text">{this.props.task.text}</span><br/><br/>
       <span className="createdAt">{this.props.task.createdAt}</span>
    </li>
);
```

and

```
return (
    <li>
       <span className="text">{this.props.task.text}</span><br/><br/>
       <span className="createdAt">{this.props.task.createdAt.toString()}</span>
    </li>
);
```

When doing this the tasks no longer display and I get the following error message when inspecting the app:

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
>   Fri Oct 07 2016 22:11:07 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)). If you
>   meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap
>   the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check
>   the render method of `Task`.

I'm still somehow confused about React. What's the meaning of this error message referring to React child? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) is a very good library to display and manipulate date and time. From your `createdAt` you can use

```
<span className="createdAt">
  {moment(this.props.task.createdAt).format(/*valid format, e.g. DD/MM/YYYY*/)
</span
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: When parsing strings, [*the format of the string should be supplied*](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) otherwise the library must guess, e.g. `moment(this.props.task.createdAt, /*format like 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm' here*/)`.